# Elixir - How to check if a String contains text or if it's a number ("453")

Tags: string, numbers, elixir

I have a list with strings

```
>> list = ["h3llo","899","3@"]
```

If a list element has at least 1 letter or special char it is considered :text, otherwise it is a :number

```
>> list = [:text, :number, :text]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2):

```elixir
case Integer.parse(str) do
  {_, ""} -> :number
  _ -> :text
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is a simple regex

```rb
iex> Regex.match?(~r/^\d+$/, "h3llo")
false
iex> Regex.match?(~r/^\d+$/, "899")
true
iex> Regex.match?(~r/^\d+$/, "3@")
false
```

Comment: `if str =~ ~r/[^\d]/, do: :text, else: :number`. The reason I didn't suggest a regex is because I think it's better to use the built-in parsing features when possible, plus regexes are difficult to read and can get ugly quickly. I also did some benchmarks, and the regex seems to be 4-5 times slower than the integer parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.contains?](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#contains?/2) works very well, follows one example extracted of documentation:

`String.contains?("elixir of life", "of")`